# ¿Alguien me puede explicar estas dos clases en C++?

Tags: c++, poo

Tenemos dos clases, **Clase1** y **Clase2**, cada una con sus variables y métodos, pero en **Clase1** hay un método que se añade una **Clase2** (addClase2), ¿alguien puede explicarme cómo funciona? ¿Cuál es su relación? No entiendo nada.
Gracias de antemano.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. El tema que buscas es Herencia (de Clases) es de Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO). Puedes encontrar material de lectura y/o videos del tema. Suerte.

Comment: No necesariamente es herencia.. capaz clase 1 solo tiene un puntero a un objeto del tipo clase 2....

Comment: El código real se entendería mejor.

Comment: Es una relación de composición, en donde Clase 1 representa el todo y Clase 2 una parte de ese todo. Las partes son construidas y destruidas junto con el todo. La composición liga la existencia de los componentes a la de la clase compuesta, un objeto solamente puede pertenecer a una composición. Al contrario de la composición que permite elegir si vamos a tener 0, 1 o N elementos con los que interactuar del mismo tipo, la herencia se relaciona en una forma 1:1.

Comment: Por ejemplo, un carro ligero está compuesto por ruedas, volante, etc., es decir, tiene elementos o usa elementos para hacer todas las funciones que puede realizar. Tomando el caso de las ruedas, es una composición en la que la clase Carro es el todo y la clase Rueda es la parte; ahora, si fueras a crear una instancia de la clase Carro, tendrías que agregarle las instancias correspondientes de la clase Rueda, para eso es útil el método addClase2(...)

Comment: @Firefly ¡Muchísimas gracias! Justo eso es lo que buscaba información, pero no sabía cómo se llama